# Ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' , файл содержит только целые числа

Tags: python

```
f = open('26.txt')
sp = [int(i) for i in f]
count_users = (int(len(sp)))
count_places = sp[1]
a = []
for i in range(count_users):
    i = int(f.readline())
    a.append(i)

ошибка: line 7, in <module>
i = int(f.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

**фрагмент файла:**
8200
970
34
35
4
30
18
```

Comment: Файл, кроме "целых чисел", содержит еще и переводы строк '\n', которые надо удалять перед преобразованием. Используйте `.rstrip()`, например

Comment: Похоже там у вас пустая строка где-то есть, возможно в конце файла

Comment: И вообще зачем вы два раза из одного файла читаете? Один раз вы его уже прочитали и получили список чисел. Возможно ошибка из-за того, что вы читаете файл, который уже прочитан и закончился

Comment: Вы уже прочитали все строки из файла одним циклом, потом еще раз вторым циклом еще раз прочитать, но конец файла уже достигнут, readline возвращает только пустую строку. Не понятно зачем вообще второй цикл, у вас уже все данные в списке sp.